# HTTPS on Elastic Beanstalk Flask application

Tags: python, ssl, encryption, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been trying get SSL enabled on my AWS Elastic Beanstalk(eb) application with not much luck so far.

After following the [documentation for configuring https access on eb](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html), I created a self-signed certificate which I believe to be enough if one just wants encryption.

I created a eb environment which used a load balancer and after uploading the certificate, I was able to use it and pick the secure listening port (8443).

On the EC2 load balancer, I created a listener for

```
HTTPS   8443    HTTP    80  <cert file>
```

I then gave the load balancer and the eb instance a security group that had the rule:

```
Custom TCP Rule     TCP     8443     0.0.0.0/0
```

I also included a config in .ebextensions pointing like the documentation told me:

```
Resources:
  sslSecurityGroupIngress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupName: {Ref : <security_group_name>}
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 8443
      FromPort: 8443
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/8443
```

Then in my flask application the application had these parameters:

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
from flask_sslify import SSLify

context = SSL.Context(SSL.TLSv1_2_METHOD)
context.use_privatekey_file('/home/ec2-user/privatekey.pem')
context.use_certificate_file('/home/ec2-user/server.crt')

basic_auth = BasicAuth(application)
sslify = SSLify(application)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8443, ssl_context=context)
```

Now when I go to the instance's public IP prefixed with https:// I get this:

[Google Chrome Connection info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaTmU.png) (can't post images with current rep ughh)

Which makes me think that I have the encryption I'm after but the Flask server connection log still shows clear requests (expected to see jumbled, encrypted request info).

When I connect with the *.elasticbeanstalk.com address I get nothing.

So I guess I have two questions:

1) **Does this mean I have encryption?**

2) **Why can't I access the instance with my elasticbeanstalk url?**

Answer (score 0):

Your ELB config is listen HTTPS request on port 8443 and make a proxy request to EC2 HTTP port. So, your EC2 must listen on HTTP port. But, it means that you terminate your SSL request on ELB.

If you want your EC2 listen HTTPS request on port 8443, your ELB config should be:

```
HTTPS   8443    HTTPS   8443  <cert_file>
```