# How does one configure a Python 3 webapp for https on AWS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, https

I am deploying a Python 3 Flask app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, and I need to configure it for https.  I followed the instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/SSL.SingleInstance.html) to the letter, and I optimistically used the second example [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/SSLPython.SingleInstance.html) replacing 2.7 with 3.4.  Somewhat predictably, it didn't work; when I try to load the server's URL with https it tries for awhile to load a secure connection and then times out.

I don't really know what I'm doing, so maybe I'm missing something fundamental.  But I'm worried that the problem is that the configuration needs to be a little different for python 3 (there are some nontrivial differences between AWS's 2.6 and 2.7 examples).  Any ideas?

Comment: (By the way, the web server works fine without https.)

Comment: Does this SO question help by any chance?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705785/python-3-https-webserver

Comment: @Saroekin That certainly looks like it would help create a local https server (which I admittedly haven't tried), but AWS requires a lot of idiosyncratic configuration.

Comment: Gotcha, I'm not entirely sure what to do here; though I'm linking some articles that I feel may help. What about this one for example?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html

Comment: @Saroekin Indeed, if you click on "Configuring SSL for Single-Instance Environments" in your link then you will arrive at the first link that I posted in my question.

Comment: Haha, wow, okay, yeah sorry I missed that. I'll actually submit some relevant helpful info. if or when I come across it. I'll scan through some more examples and/or articles.

Comment: Aha! I think I've found the answer to your problem located in this SO question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31486546/https-on-elastic-beanstalk-flask-application

Hope it helps.